# C#でVisioの図形内テキストの属性情報を取得したい

Tags: c#, visio

C#でVisioの図形内テキストの属性情報を取得したいです。
具体的には以下の3つです。

- font-family
- font-size
- font-color

↓取得したい図形
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

↓図形を選択して「シェイプシートの表示」を押したときの情報
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

コードはPageオブジェクトのShape.Charactersから取得できそうですが、どのように書けば取得できるか不明です。(探した限り見つからなかった)

↓このページを見る限り、属性は用意されていそうなので取得できると思っています。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/visio.characters.charprops

例えば

```
var size = page.Shapes[0].Characters[visCharacterSize]
```

みたいに指定して取れるよいのですが、できませんでした。

どなたかご教授よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: Office製品はVBA関連の方が情報ありそうなので、そちらから探してみた方が良いかもしれません。https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=visio+shape+font+%22vba%22+-excel Cellの数式からアクセスするような雰囲気…？https://www.mster.co.jp/bbslog/cgi-bin/visio0138/mibbs.cgi?mo=p&fo=auto&tn=0036 http://www.interq.or.jp/chubu/r6/visio/DVS_17_Automating_formulas812.htm